# What are the rules and logic for time travel set in Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, time-travel, avengers-endgame, loki-2021

In this [article by Vanity Fair](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2021/06/loki-michael-waldron-doctor-strange-star-wars-rick-and-morty), Michael Waldron talks about the rules for time travel set by *Loki* (2021):

> Marvel already made its case for how time travel works in Avengers: Endgame, but that, Waldron points out, “is the way the Avengers understand it.” With a TV show it’s a little different. “I was always very acutely aware of the fact that there’s a week between each of our episodes and these fans are going to do exactly what I would do, which is pick this apart. **We wanted to create a time-travel logic that was so airtight it could sustain over six hours.** There’s some time-travel sci-fi concepts here that I’m eager for my Rick and Morty colleagues to see.”

This article was posted before Loki began airing. Now that *Loki* has finished airing and we've seen the full breadth of time travel involved in the story, what are the specific rules and logic that govern time travel in the TV series (and most likely also the larger Marvel Cinematic Universe)?

*Avengers: Endgame* had [that excellent scene](https://youtu.be/OstryGGxgXo) where they laid out the rules for time travel as the Avengers understood it and said it doesn't work like the *Back to the Future*:

> *Professor Hulk*: I don’t know why everyone believes that, but that isn’t true. Think about it: If you travel to the past, that past becomes your future, and your former present becomes the past! Which can’t now be changed by your new future!

The only other scene I remember in *Avengers: Endgame* was the one where [the Ancient One talks about not destroying timelines](https://youtu.be/RNBKKGM1w88?t=52):

> *Ancient One*: I'm sorry, I can't help you, Bruce. If I give up the Time Stone to help your reality, I'm dooming my own.
> *Bruce Banner*: With all due respect, I'm not sure that science really supports that.
> *Ancient One*: The Infinity Stones create what you experience as the flow of time. Remove one stone and that flow splits. Now, this may benefit your reality but my new one, not so much. In this new branched reality, without our chief weapon against the forces of darkness, our world will be over run. Millions will suffer. So, tell me Doctor, can your science prevent all that?
> *Bruce Banner*: No, but we can erase it. Because once we are done with the stones, we can return each one to it's own time line at the moment it was taken. So, chronologically, in that reality, they never left.

In *Loki*, our understanding of time travel was stretched across the whole TV series and we didn't get an easy two scene explanation of how time travel worked. The episode where Loki gets oriented has a video that explains time travel and timelines as the Time Variance Authority understands it, but we learn more about timelines and how time travel works as the series progresses.

How are the rules of time travel in *Loki* similar to those in *Endgame*, and how do they differ? What new rules are created in *Loki*? What are the specific time-travel logic rules that Michael Waldron talks about in the article with Vanity Fair? What do the rules for timelines and time travel look like for the future Marvel Cinematic Universe films?

Comment: I'd re-write the last two paragraphs by including a technical description of the scene laid out in Avengers Endgame that you mentioned, then asking posters to compare and contrast it with the time travel rules in Loki to provide you with the answer that you're looking for.

Comment: @Phyneas I've edited my post based on your feedback, let me know if that's what you had in mind!

Comment: Looks great, it has more detail to work off of and you've already produced a couple of good answers!

Comment: Ruled by the demands of plot? Did not strike me as hard sci fi (or hard magic, for that matter).

Comment: Loki is more or less like Asimov's "The End of Eternity", in many ways.

Answer (score 11):

There's an important part of the TVA and the "time travel" we see in Loki that the other answers here miss: it exists outside of time and space.

> **What did you envision as the look for "Loki"? There's so much going on, and the TVA has its own unique mix of styles that adds to Loki's and the viewers' disorientation.**
>
> [...]
>
> Loki, for example, when he's arrested, he goes through these processing rooms. And Kasra was like, "Oh, we should make them cubes that he like falls through." And I thought that was so funny. And the idea of having the cat in one of them because **I really wanted the TVA to feel like it was a real challenge because it's this office environment, but it exists outside of time and space.** Something with me and Kasra was always talking about what how do we make this feel like a real, living, breathing office space.
>
> <sub>[Salon, The existential crisis of "Loki"](https://www.salon.com/2021/06/13/loki-tva-identity-kate-herron/)</sub>

As such it would mean that the "time travel" we see in *Loki* from the TVA isn't actually time travel. What is actually happening is the Minutemen are jumping in and out of the timeline. There's no contradiction to the time travel rules setup in *Endgame* because the actions we are seeing are different to inner timeline time travel.

The rules that were setup for *Loki* weren't necessarily for time travel but rather for timelines. How do timelines work? How does the multiverse work? How does the Sacred Timeline work? etc. That is what had to be airtight not time travel because when you think about it that isn't really what is happening in *Loki*.

Comment: I'd argue that time travel rules are still important in _Loki_ (or at least, they should be), because while it's true that the agents of the TVA are not time travellers in the conventional sense, they can still affect the Sacred Timeline to the same extent as time travellers, and the Variants they hunt can as well. The conclusion of Episode 6 also suggests that the history of the TVA itself can be altered... somehow.

Comment: @LogicDictates I'd argue time travel rules don't apply. The time travel rules tell us how to _split_ a timeline. The rules in _Loki_ show us how timelines can take different paths but they don't split. That's quite a difference.

Comment: Could you explain that difference in more detail? I could post it as a new question if that works for you.

Comment: @LogicDictates In Endgame the Ancient One explains that a single timeline can split into 6/7 by taking an Infinity Stone out of it. In Loki we see timelines diverge from the Sacred Timeline and are reset by the TVA. I.e. they don't actually split themselves but are rather moving away from the predetermined path and need to be reset so they that stay on said path... the timeline that diverges though never splits. (At least that's my interpretation of what we see that I believe to be correct).

Comment: I'm still not clear about the difference between actually splitting, and just moving away from the predetermined path. The fault may not lie with your reasoning though, but with the show itself being extremely vague about the rules, and not necessarily consistent. I may go ahead and ask a new question related to this, because I'm pretty sure it can't be resolved in the comments, if it can be resolved at all.

Comment: Timelines are _pruned_ by the TVA, i.e.. removed, they're not pushed back into line or something.  If they hadn't branched into their own separate thing, then the Sacred Timeline would be pruned as well.

Comment: I'll admit there's a large gap in my understanding of the pruning process.  Using female Loki as an example - she gets arrested and a prune explosion goes off.  I'd assume the effect is limited and that parallel universe she was from goes on having forgotten about her but not do anything divergent enough to trigger a multiverse war.  Some of these Loki existed for quite some time with alternate biographies.  So I don't think sacred Loki transformed into a girl one time and TVA put her back on the path like the TVA cartoon.  I assume in her universe she was always a girl Loki or near to it

Comment: @lucasbachmann There’s a question on how physically different variants can exist. I agree with your interpretation that they are always different. I think it’s more to do with actions and outcomes rather than physical differences.

Comment: "There's no contradiction to the time travel rules setup in Endgame because the actions we are seeing are different to inner timeline time travel." It's not, though? In both cases, the people involved are using the Quantum Realm to travel through time.

Comment: @lucasbachmann "I'd assume the effect is limited and that parallel universe she was from goes on having forgotten about her" This is wrong. The parallel universe she's from gets deleted from existence, and anything that survives the deletion gets sent to the Void at the End of Time.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the rules don’t necessarily differ, it has just been explored more in Loki.

Consider that in Endgame, like the scene described in your question, we know that the flow of time creates new branches when the stones are removed. In Loki, we learn that these branches can happen for another reason, and that is seemingly that variants can cause these branches. Now, how other variants than just Loki (or the other Loki variants) really began is the real question. I predict we will have more insight into that in Multiverse of Madness, and I suspect that either Mordo or Scarlet Witch have something to do with it, but I digress.

It seems that the rules haven’t changed, we’ve just learned more about the flow of time and the multiverse in general. I suspect we will continue to learn more and it will all be built off of the foundation established regarding time travel in Endgame.

Answer (score 2):

In the MCU any time travel is to an identical parallel universe.   Thus no paradoxes but the new universe may proceed slightly differently. However the Hulk explains this in the worst way possible and people who should know better still don't get it.  (The 1990s series Time Trax had the same rules.  As did 2000s Art Bell internet conspiracy John Titor)

Anyway Ant-man and Tony Stark realized that at the quantum realm level of reality time travel is possible - it's part of the landscape at that level. What Loki demonstrated is that it doesn't take macro level time travel events like Avengers on a mission to split a universe.  It happens all the time everywhere.  Note I don't think this is the multiverse interpretation of Quantum physics vs Copenhagen.  Rather I think I just means some quantum realm time travel took place.   Maybe a neutrino or a photon took a wormhole to the past.

This provides a degree of freedom for anyone- but particularly Lokis- to make a different choice than what the sacred timeline had.

What Loki established is that an organization will jump to these parallel universes and delete the parts they consider divergent to the timeline they want.  Hulk couldn't know that. Once the TVA stopped doing that a Fractal multiverse takes off and gets out of control for the next phase of the MCU.

Comment: Michael Crichton's Timeline used a similar system, where the "time" travelers actually go to a parallel world of medieval France. (Though that story has a gaping plot hole where the team is rescued with the help of a message they leave to be found in the "future.")

Comment: There's a fascinating short story in Exhalation by Ted Chiang where someone discovers a way to create a quantum phenomenon event (in which the spin of a particle is either in one direction or the other) in such a way that the now two parallel universes can communicate with each other after the event. It's implied in the story that these events are happening constantly all around us, but only with this device can you have any possible connection to one of these parallel universes.

Comment: @jeffronicus: in which sense the world is "parallel"? Prof Johnston left a note to be found by his team (he knew where they were digging). André's grave was found at the end of the novel. To me there is no parallel world.

Comment: @WoJ From the NYT's 1999 review of the novel: "Ostensibly, Crichton's lack of interest in the possibilities of his own plot line stems from the fact that, strictly speaking, his protagonists are going back to the 1357 of a universe almost exactly parallel to ours -- they're traveling in space, not time. But that's just a cheat, and an inconsistent one at that. (A pair of eyeglasses that the Professor leaves in the ''other'' 14th century turns up in an archaeological dig in ''our'' universe.)"

Comment: @jeffronicus those eyeglasses are kind of similar to the captain America problem.  Either he came back to his original universe as an old man OR...our universe was the parallel universe for some other universe's Captain America to live his life in.  (Now I absolutely do not think the creator's intended that latter option quite the opposite they said he lived out his life in an alternate universe.)

Comment: @jeffronicus I do not understand that explanation. They have a device that allows them to instantly travel to the past. Prof Johnston leaves 1999 and lands in 1357. The glasses he left in 1357 spent ~750 years there, to be found in 1999 as part of the excavation. Then the whole team travels to 1357 (they are not in 1999 anymore). Finally, they come back to 1999 (after having spent some time in 1357 and not being in 1999), except for André who stays there. He dies in that period and they discover his grave in 1999, a grave from 13xx. I do not see where the "parallelism" is.

Comment: @WoJ If it doesn't make sense, well, blame Crichton. The novel explicitly explains that because time travel is "impossible," the genius inventor has created a quantum device that connects to a parallel world where it's still 1357, so nothing the travelers can do will affect our present. That's why the glasses are a gaping plot hole; Crichton never explains how they came to be in *our* world if the professor left them in a parallel world.

Comment: @jeffronicus: ahhhh, I get it now. I read the book 20 years ago and I forgot that part. I thought that it was "normal" time travel. I stand corrected.